# Angular ViewChild with ng-template not get all innerHTML

Tags: angular, viewchild, ng-template

I have this angular component.html

```
<div #statsToCopy>
        
    <ng-template #modalCumulativePreview let-modal>

    <div class="modal-body px-1 cumulative-image-preview" tabindex="0" ngbAutofocus>

        <div class="content-wrapper">

            <div class="content-body">

                <div *blockUI="'card-cumu-block'">

                    <div class="stats">

                        <div class="row mt-0"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </ng-template>
</div>
```

and in component.ts:

```
@ViewChild("statsToCopy") statsToCopy: any;

  preview() {
    console.log(this.uiData.statsToCopy.nativeElement)
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.preview();
  }
```

but in console of browser I got this:

```
<div _ngcontent-lul-c234=""><!--container--></div>
```

This make other package failed to work. because I want to get innHTML to be captured to image using both packages: 'html2canvas', 'copy-image-clipboard'. but not worked because of the error above. any help please.